# Python code to read the split line, match and print

Tags: python

Please note the input file has the data as follows.

```
COM*IP**Home*57667*work*5646578*cell*45767~
```

I need python code to split this line using separator *, the if the 4th element is Home, work or cell then populate the next element "57667" accordingly. Similarly the same check should be done for 6th and 8th element and the next element should be printed. How to achieve this?

line_starts_with ('COM*',line):
`your text`s=tuple(line.split(*))
`your text`If S[3] is 'HOME':
`your text`phone = s[4]
`your text`phone.strip()

Comment: The data contains 'Home' but you're testing for 'HOME'. Why?

Answer (score 0):

It is *unclear* what your expected output is. If your expected output is this `{'Home': '57667', 'Work': '5646578', 'Cell': '45767'}`, then try this:

```
line = 'COMIP**Home57667work5646578cell45767~'
data = line.split('*')
phone_numbers = {}
if data[3] == 'Home':
    phone_numbers['Home'] = data[4]
if data[5] == 'work':
    phone_numbers['Work'] = data[6]
if data[7] == 'cell':
    phone_numbers['Cell'] = data[8]
print(phone_numbers)
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/214173).

Comment: @JamesRisner The op's question wasn't very clear... perhaps they clarified after my comment. I'm not sure if you took note, but the post had two downvotes when I posted.

Comment: You know about the commenting privilege which you do not have, so well that you can even put it into words. You are aware of the rule https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead . In that situation please do not decide to misuse a different mechanism (an answer) for something it is not meant for and which you are not allowed yet to do.

Comment: Please phrase this as an explained conditional answer, in order to avoid the impression of asking a clarification question instead of answering (for which a comment should be used instead of an answer, compare https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead ). For example like "If your problem is ... then the solution is to .... because .... ."

Comment: Thanks for the answer guidelines. I will edit my post to adhere to them. Though,  I still do think the question was unclear and in need of clarification, I can see how it'd be problematic if a bunch of answers included 'I can't comment because of my reputation.'

Comment: @IftikharRamnandan The issue isn't that you said you couldn't comment. The issue is you provided an answer to an unclear question at all. The question should get clarified before an answer is provided. So your edited answer as of 5 minutes ago is no different than the original answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use explicit subscripts unless absolutely necessary. This is more flexible:

```
s = 'COM*IP**Home*57667*work*5646578*cell*45767~'
# take the entire string if it does not contain tilde
# if there's one or more tilde take everything that precedes the first occurrence
t, *_ = s.split('~')
tokens = t.split('*')
HWC = set(('work', 'home', 'cell'))
for i in range(3, len(tokens)-1, 2):
    if tokens[i].lower() in HWC:
        print(tokens[i+1])
```

**Output:**

```
57667
5646578
45767
```